# Apache mod_rewrite rules aren't triggering?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, mod-rewrite, http, redirect

I have an archive of the Twitch Plays Pokemon Reddit updates on my server (http://flarn2006.dyndns.org/tppupdates/). Some of them include links of the format "/u/*username*", which is valid on Reddit, but not on my site. (I'm not referring to the links on the very right; those are correct.) I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to automatically redirect these links, so if it gets a request for "/u/*anything*" with a referrer containing "/tppupdates/", it will redirect it to Reddit.

I have the following in my apache2.conf:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /tppupdates/
RewriteRule ^/u/(.*)$ http://reddit.com/u/$1 [R=301]
```

Yet when I click on one of the offending links, it just gives me a 404. What's wrong?

Comment: What do your rewrite logs say?

Comment: @EEAA I didn't even know there was such a thing. In /var/log/apache2 I don't see any files called "rewrite.log" or anything obvious like that; what are the files called? Are they in another directory?

Comment: Your RewriteCond doesn't look right to me, I think you'll need to include the full URL, you could probably even remove the RewriteCond and it would work.

Comment: Where is this rewrite instruction located? in .htaccess or in directory section of your VHost? If yes, remove first "/" in RewriteRule, it is per directory context and have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule , paragraph "What is matched"

Comment: @Zimmi It was in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, but I created a directory called `u` in `/var/www`, and put the following in an .htaccess in that directory, which solved my problem:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /tppupdates/
    RewriteRule (.*) http://reddit.com/u/$1 [R=301]

You should submit that as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, here a more complete answer for this :

The rewrite engine does not work exactly the same way depending on the location of the rewrite instructions. There are basically 2 contexts for the instructions: per server and per dir. They are as follow:

```
| in apache2.conf files:
|
|   here it is per server
|
|   <VirtualHost>
|
|        per server
|
|        <Directory, Location, File or Proxy>
|
|           per dir !!!
|
|        </Directory, etc>
|   </VirtualHost>
```

In .htaccess : always per dir context

In per server context, use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /tppupdates/
RewriteRule ^/u/(.*)$ http://reddit.com/u/$1 [R=301]
```

And in per dir context, use this, if you are in web root folder, according to your example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /tppupdates/
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ http://reddit.com/u/$1 [R=301]
```

Please note the absence of first "`/`" in the RewriteRule.

With those rules you do not need to create a directory called /u.

Some more infos in apache docs: [RewriteRule, what is matched](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [tech details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/tech.html)

And are you sure you want this `RewriteCond`?